# Keras repeat elements throwing ValueError List argument 'indices' to 'SparseConcat' Op with length 0 shorter than minimum length 2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, unsupervised-learning, aspect, attention-model

I am trying to implement the code for Unsupervised Aspect Extraction from the code available [here](https://github.com/ruidan/Unsupervised-Aspect-Extraction).
[Link](https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~leews/publications/acl17.pdf) to the paper
While implementing Attention class in ml_layers.py, i am getting error in call function at line

```
y = K.repeat_elements(y, self.steps, axis=1)
```

Complete code of the function is given below:

```
def call(self, input_tensor, mask=None):
    x = input_tensor[0]
    y = input_tensor[1]
    mask = mask[0]

    y = K.transpose(K.dot(self.W, K.transpose(y)))
    y = K.expand_dims(y, axis=-2)
    y = K.repeat_elements(y, self.steps, axis=1)
    eij = K.sum(x*y, axis=-1)

    if self.bias:
        b = K.repeat_elements(self.b, self.steps, axis=0)
        eij += b

    eij = K.tanh(eij)
    a = K.exp(eij)

    if mask is not None:
        a *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())

    a /= K.cast(K.sum(a, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())
    return a
```

The error is as follows 
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    model = create_model(ortho_reg, neg_size, emb_dim, aspect_size, emb_path, maxlen, vocab)

File "/home/fractaluser/Projects/workspace/UnsupervisedAspectExtraction/code/model.py", line 32, in create_model
    att_weights = Attention(name='att_weights')([e_w, y_s])

File "/home/fractaluser/anaconda3/envs/venv_keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 457, in **call**
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)

File "/home/fractaluser/Projects/workspace/UnsupervisedAspectExtraction/code/my_layers.py", line 58, in call
    y = K.repeat_elements(y, self.steps, axis=1)

File "/home/fractaluser/anaconda3/envs/venv_keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2093, in repeat_elements
    return concatenate(x_rep, axis)

File "/home/fractaluser/anaconda3/envs/venv_keras/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1954, in concatenate
    return tf.sparse_concat(axis, tensors)

File "/home/fractaluser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/fractaluser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/sparse_ops.py", line 316, in sparse_concat
    gen_sparse_ops.sparse_concat(inds, vals, shapes, axis, name=name))

File "/home/fractaluser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_sparse_ops.py", line 911, in sparse_concat
    concat_dim=concat_dim, name=name)

File "/home/fractaluser/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 570, in _apply_op_helper
    (input_name, op_type_name, len(values), num_attr.minimum))

ValueError: List argument 'indices' to 'SparseConcat' Op with length 0 shorter than minimum length 2.

Could not find any solution on internet. Please help

Comment: doesn't that mean that `self.steps` is 0?

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this problem

`AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'image_dim_ordering'`,

So I have to 
modify the
`K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th'('tf') ==> K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first'(channels_last)`

after that, I met the same problem as you. But My problem is there still someplace haven't been correct. After I modify all the places. The problem is gone.
I hope this can help you.